# how to brew install guile 1.8 on mac

Tags: macos, homebrew, guile, texmacs

I want to compile texmacs on my mac. It requires guile1.8 however I can only got an 2.2 version by `brew install guile`. I used `brew search guile` and there is only one guile. How can I install guile1.8 using homebrew?

Comment: Check the git history of homebrew, there were commits about guile 1.8. And it's not necessary to install it with homebrew, why not just download it and build yourself?

Answer (score 2):

Just use my repo:

```
# install guile 1.8
git clone git@github.com:sadhen/homebrew-sadhen.git
cd homebrew-sadhen
brew install guile@1.8.rb
```

Comment: `brew tap sadhen/sadhen && brew install guile@1.8` does the trick 